# on button click update jttextfield and calculate with newly entered value?

Tags: java, jtextfield

In my Java GUI there are 4 `JTextField`s. The goal is to enter default values for 3 textfields (example .8 in code below) and calculate the value and display the calculation into the 4th textfield. The user should then be able to change the values of the numbers within the `JTextField` and then press the calculate button again to get the new values to recalculate and display them.

Problem: when the JTextfields are edited and the calculate button is pressed it does not calculate with the new numbers but instead with the old initial values.

```
JTextField S = new JTextField();
S.setText(".8");
String Stext = S.getText();
final double Snumber = Double.parseDouble(Stext);
.... *same setup for Rnumber*
.... *same setup for Anumber*
....
JButton btnCalculate_1 = new JButton("Calculate");
btnCalculate_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
  int valuec = (int) Math.ceil(((Snumber*Rnumber)/Anumber)/8);
  String stringValuec = String.valueOf(valuec);
NewTextField.setText(stringCalc);
}
```

I have checked several posts and tried:

[How Do I Get User Input from a TextField and Convert it to a Double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451421/how-do-i-get-user-input-from-a-textfield-and-convert-it-to-a-double)

[Using JTextField for user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285973/using-jtextfield-for-user-input)

for the basics. However whenever trying to adapt it to my code eclipse returns various errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using This code.

```
class a extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
JTextField t1,t2,t3;
a()
{

    setLayout(null);
    t1 = new JTextField();
    t2 = new JTextField();
    t3 = new JTextField();
    JButton B1 = new JButton("Calculate");

    t3.setEditable(false);

    t1.setBounds(10,10,100,30);
    t2.setBounds(10,40,100,30);
    t3.setBounds(10,70,100,30);

    B1.setBounds(50, 110, 80, 50);

    add(t1);
    add(t2);
    add(t3);
    add(B1);

    B1.addActionListener(this);

    setSize(200,200);
    setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new a();
    }
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    double Snumber = Double.parseDouble(t1.getText());
    double Rnumber = Double.parseDouble(t2.getText());
    double Anumber = Snumber+Rnumber;
    t3.setText(String.valueOf(Anumber));

}
```

}

Comment: change it according to your functionality.

Answer (score 2):

use `S.getText()` *inside* the `actionPerformed()` method.
The code inside actionperformed block is invoked on the button press and the code outside it remains unaffected.
So once you run your code and insert values to text fields, it assigns the a value but it does not change the same when you change the value and press calculate button

Comment: I added  `S.getText()` inside the `actionperformed()`. It then says make S "final" which I did. However, this does not change anything. It still calculates with the default values.

Comment: dont make S final. Make it a global Jtextfeild

Comment: Thank you...it still does not change anything though.

Comment: and why are you using final here : "final double Snumber = Double.parseDouble(Stext);"? Final variable's value cannot be changed

Comment: I did it because otherwise my program does not run, it just returns multiple errors.